# Unable to add a row to Solr

Tags: solr, pysolr

Im trying to add a row to the Solr Index but it does not get added.

I get a response but not sure what to infer from the response.

What information the response provides here? How do I get the exception?

```
>>> c = SolrConnection('http://localhost:8983/solr')
>>> c
<SolrConnection (url=http://localhost:8983/solr, persistent=True, post_headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}, reconnects=0)>
>>> l =  [{'document_type': 'demo', 'id': 'demo11234', 'deco_name': 'test'}]
>>> c.add_many(l)
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<response>\n<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst>\n</response>\n'
>>> try:
...    c.add_many(l)
... except:
...    print "error"
...
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<response>\n<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">2</int></lst>\n</response>\n'
```